How do I use the Instagram graph API with React to fetch posts where I am tagged?
I'm new to development with Instagram APIs and am trying to make a React based application that uses Instagram's graph API in order to fetch posts where my professional account is mentioned and display them on my webpage. I tried going through the Meta documentation on how to use their graph API, but I don't quite get where to start and I am getting confused with all the steps I need to take to just make my first API call. The Meta guide is https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started . Any help regarding this on the steps or links to resources that can guide me through this would be great! Thanks in advance!
I have tried making a react application, but in one of the steps it says to create a facebook login app on my meta dashboard first, I did do that, but I am not getting access to the required permission, instgram_basic, etc.
